# Angular routing issue without hash

Tags: angularjs, router

I am facing issue with angular routing without using "#".

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

On first load routing without # is working fine but when refresh(F5) page something wrong with angular routing. Please suggest any solution except Url rewriting on server side.

Comment: *"Please suggest any solution except Url rewriting on server side"* <- why? I don't think there's a way to accomplish this without it other than **not** using HTML5 mode.

Comment: have you resolved this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change how your file is being served. If you are using **webpack-dev-server** you need to add this(see [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)) :

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

If you are using nginx you need to change how the it serve file:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```